# How to update Git refspec using porcelain/tooling rather than string-replace

Tags: git

I am not seemingly able to find a way to update the refspec using the existing tooling.

For this specific case/context, the repository may have an existing refspec that I can not work with. Therefore, I need to preemptively update it to a wildcard every time. Because I do not know the state, I need to use a regular-expression replacement to identify that expression in the config and then replace it with the wildcard expression (`'+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'`). This would be more elegant if I could just use git-config or git-remote to set something else. Surely there's some way to do their via the porcelain/plumbing somewhere that I'm just missing?

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example, please? `'+refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/'` looks like a remote fetch line in `.git/config`.

Comment: `git config` is itself a plumbing command. You may need to quote asterisks against any *shell* expansion, but if you are driving `git config` from another program, you probably should invoke `git config` directly, rather than invoking a shell to invoke `git config`, which makes this problem vanish.

Comment: In this case, you might use `git config --get-all remote.<remote>.fetch` to read out all existing fetch lines, to diagnose what it's set to now. Note that some lines might come out of the system or per-user global config, or an included config. This makes the job harder.

Comment: The `git remote` command is pretty plumbing-ish: `git remote set-branches` is meant to be usable from a program. But it's not clear from the documentation whether `git remote set-branches <name> *` is meant to be allowed. In practice, it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: Can you explain your context with more details ? In particular : what is the starting refspec ? What kind of actions does it prevent you to do ? (is it "run git fetch manually" ? or "run a script on a CI server" ? or ...)